# Question on circle, binomial coefficient.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, circles

A circle $C$, with $n$ distinct points on its circumference. Joining any two points will form a chord.

Suppose that no three chords intercept at any one point inside $C$. Let $C_n$ be the number of such chords, In be the intersections of the chords inside $C$ and $R_n$ be the regions of $C$ bounded by an arc and/or some chords.

How should I approach this question?

Btw, the question asked to find $C_n$, $I_n$ and $R_n$ where $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$
and also binomial coefficients for each of them in terms of $n$. Let ${m\choose k } = 0$ if $m < k$.

Answer (score 1):

For $C_n$:

Each pair of points defines a chord. So $C_n$ is the number of pairs of points.

For $I_n$:

Each set of four points defines a point of intersection. So $I_n$ is the number of ways to choose 4 points out of the $n$ points.

For $R_n$:

We have $R_0=1$, $R_1=2$, $R_2=4$, $R_3=8$ and $R_4=16$.

When we have $n-1$ points on the circumference, there are $C_n$ chords and $I_{n-1}$ points of intersection of chords. If we add the $n$th point on the circumference, there will be $C_n-C_{n-1}$ additional chords and $I_n-I_{n-1}$ additional points of intersection of chords. The new chords will be cut into pieces by the original chords, and the number of new pieces is equal to the sum of the number of new chords and the number of new points of intersection. Each new piece will cut an original region into two.

$$Rn-R_{n-1}=C_n-C_{n-1}+I_n-I_{n-1}$$

Telescoping, $\displaystyle R_n=\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{2}+1$.